# How to fill in the space between two drawn plots?

Tags: pgfplots, draw, fillbetween

Someone's answered a question about the space between two drawn lines before, but I'm finding it impossible to see how their answer applies to mine and have no idea how the clips work and what I need to change them to on mine. I'm literally using latex for the sake of this one report, so I know it won't be anywhere near perfect.

I'm trying to fill in the space between the two parabolas to make it look like the water is flowing into the container. 
Any help is appreciated :)

```
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn]{revtex4}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
% water
\fill [ fill = cyan!40 ] (0, 1.75) -- (0, 0) -- (2, 0) -- (2, 1.75) (2, .45) -- (2, .55) -- (2.5, .55) -- (2.5, .45);
\draw [domain = 2.5:3.2, samples=50] plot (\x, {-2*(\x-2.5)^2+.45});
\draw [domain = 2.5:3.3, samples=50] plot (\x, {-2*(\x-2.5)^2+.55});

% box, tube
\draw [thick] (2,.45) -- (2,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,2)    (2, 2) -- (2, .55);
\draw [thick] (1.5, .45) -- (2.5, .45)    (1.5, .55) -- (2.5, .55);

% height information
\draw[dashed] (1.5, .45) -- (0, .45);
\draw (-.25, .45) -- (0, .45)    (-.25, 1.75) -- (0, 1.75);
\draw (-.125, .45) -- (-.125, .9)  node[above] {$h$}  (-.125, 1.3) -- (-.125, 1.75);

% stand
\draw [thick] (.5, 0) -- (1.5, -.5)    (.5, -.5) -- (1.5, 0);
\draw (.4, -.5) -- (1.6, -.5) -- (1.6, -.55) -- (.4, -.55);
\fill [ fill=gray ] (.4, -.5) -- (1.6, -.5) -- (1.6, -.55) -- (.4, -.55);

% jug
\fill [ fill=cyan!50 ] (2.7, -.5) -- (2.7, -.8) -- (3.7, -.8) -- (3.7, -.5);
\draw (2.7, .2) -- (2.7, -.8) -- (3.7, -.8) -- (3.7, .2);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn]{revtex4}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% water
\fill [ fill = cyan!40 ] (0, 1.75) -- (0, 0) -- (2, 0) -- (2, 1.75) (2, .45) -- (2, .55) -- (2.5, .55) -- (2.5, .45);
\fill[ fill = cyan!40 ]  plot[domain = 2.45:3.25, samples=50] (\x, {-2*(\x-2.5)^2+.45}) --  
plot[domain = 3.2:2.45, samples=50] (\x, {-2*(\x-2.5)^2+.55});
% box, tube
\draw [thick] (2,.45) -- (2,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,2)    (2, 2) -- (2, .55);
\draw [thick] (1.5, .45) -- (2.5, .45)    (1.5, .55) -- (2.5, .55);
% height information
\draw[dashed] (1.5, .45) -- (0, .45);
\draw (-.25, .45) -- (0, .45)    (-.25, 1.75) -- (0, 1.75);
\draw (-.125, .45) -- (-.125, .9)  node[above] {$h$}  (-.125, 1.3) -- (-.125, 1.75);
% stand
\draw [thick] (.5, 0) -- (1.5, -.5)    (.5, -.5) -- (1.5, 0);
\draw (.4, -.5) -- (1.6, -.5) -- (1.6, -.55) -- (.4, -.55);
\fill [ fill=gray ] (.4, -.5) -- (1.6, -.5) -- (1.6, -.55) -- (.4, -.55);
% jug
\fill [ fill=cyan!40 ] (2.7, -.5) -- (2.7, -.8) -- (3.7, -.8) -- (3.7, -.5);
\draw (2.7, .2) -- (2.7, -.8) -- (3.7, -.8) -- (3.7, .2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

like this?

[image]

differences between code and proposed solution is indicate by `% <---` with short description after then:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn]{revtex4}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
% water
\fill [ fill = cyan!40 ] (0, 1.75) -- (0, 0) -- (2, 0) -- (2, 1.75) (2, .45) -- (2, .55) -- (2.5, .55) -- (2.5, .45);
\path [name path=A, domain = 2.5:3.2, samples=50] plot (\x, {-2*(\x-2.5)^2+.45}); % <-- added name
\path [name path=B, domain = 2.5:3.3, samples=50] plot (\x, {-2*(\x-2.5)^2+.55}); % <-- added
\tikzfillbetween[of=A and B]{cyan!50}; % <-- added fill between paths A and B

% box, tube
\draw [thick] (2,.45) -- (2,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,2)    (2, 2) -- (2, .55);
\draw [thick] (1.5, .45) -- (2.5, .45)    (1.5, .55) -- (2.5, .55);

% height information
\draw[dashed] (1.5, .45) -- (0, .45);
\draw (-.25, .45) -- (0, .45)    (-.25, 1.75) -- (0, 1.75);
\draw (-.125, .45) -- (-.125, .9)  node[above] {$h$}  (-.125, 1.3) -- (-.125, 1.75);

% stand
\draw [thick] (.5, 0) -- (1.5, -.5)    (.5, -.5) -- (1.5, 0);
\draw (.4, -.5) -- (1.6, -.5) -- (1.6, -.55) -- (.4, -.55);
\fill [ fill=gray ] (.4, -.5) -- (1.6, -.5) -- (1.6, -.55) -- (.4, -.55);

% jug
\fill [ fill=cyan!50 ] (2.7, -.5) -- (2.7, -.8) -- (3.7, -.8) -- (3.7, -.5);
\draw (2.7, .2) -- (2.7, -.8) -- (3.7, -.8) -- (3.7, .2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thank god, I didn't notice the command was changed from \draw to \path, thank you so much! Thought I might have to block off the ends of the parabola trail, but i don't! Thanks again :)